# Access Query Count Records in Another Table without Requery?

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to make a report where I need to know the the count of items from another table like this

```
+----------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
| Sale No. | Widget |                 Total Sold                 |
+----------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
|      123 | foo    | Dcount(another table where widget = "foo") |
|      456 | bar    | Dcount(another table where widget = "bar") |
+----------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
```

.

```
SELECT  [Sale No.]
        , Widget
        , Dcount("SELECT foo from whatever where widget = " & widget) as [Total Sold]
FROM    sometable
```

Unfortunately this queries the database for every record, for such a report that must be run daily this isn't really efficient.

Is there a way to query this once, and either through VBA or some SQL I don't know to hold the query in memory or the counts of each unique item. Basically query the other table just the one time instead of N times.

---

Here's a more accurate table that reflects my data closer

```
+----------+------------+---------+------------------+
| Employee | Department | Policy  | Review Requested |
+----------+------------+---------+------------------+
|      123 | Sales      | PlanABC | TRUE             |
|      456 | Sales      | PlanABC | TRUE             |
|      789 | Accounting | PlanXYZ | FALSE            |
|   101112 | Accounting | PlanXYZ | TRUE             |
|   131415 | Sales      | PlanXYZ | FALSE            |
|   161718 | Admin      | PlanJKL | TRUE             |
+----------+------------+---------+------------------+
```

And the result I'm going for

```
+------------+----------+---------+----------------------+
| Department | Employee | Policy  | Count of All Polices |
+------------+----------+---------+----------------------+
| Sales      |      123 | PlanABC |                    2 |
| Sales      |      456 | PlanABC |                    2 |
| Accounting |   101112 | PlanXYZ |                    3 |
| Admin      |   161718 | PlanJKL |                    1 |
+------------+----------+---------+----------------------+
```

Comment: You could join your tables and use the SQL `Count` rather than the Access `DCOUNT`.  How are your original tables set up?

Comment: Is `[Sale No.]` unique in the table?

Comment: There's no real logical join as far as I can see. It's actually the same table, the query is get all records where status="foo" count all records that have the same widget regardless of status from this table.

Sale No. Was just an abstraction there's some other info that I'm reporting on that is not unique.

Comment: Should there also be `Sales/131415/PlanXYZ/3` and `Accounting/789/PlanXYZ/3` in those results?

Answer (score 0):

If your table is set up as below:

```
| Sale No | Widget |
|---------|--------|
| 1       | Foo    |
| 2       | Bar    |
| 3       | Foo    |
| 4       | Foo    |
| 5       | Bar    |
| 6       | Foo    |
| 7       | Foo    |
| 8       | Bar    |
| 9       | Bar    |
| 10      | Foo    |
```

You can't include the `Sale No` as it will group the values on that.

```
 SELECT     Widget
            , COUNT(Widget) AS [Total Sold]    
 FROM       sometable
 GROUP BY   Widget
```

Just adding the Widgets and grouping on them will return:

```
| Widget | Total Sold |
|--------|------------|
| Bar    | 4          |
| Foo    | 6          |
```

If, on the other hand, your `Sale No` field is duplicated then you can get a count per `Sale No`.

```
| Sale No | Widget |
|---------|--------|
| 1       | Foo    |
| 1       | Bar    |
| 5       | Foo    |
| 5       | Foo    |
| 5       | Bar    |
| 7       | Foo    |
| 7       | Foo    |
| 7       | Bar    |
| 7       | Bar    |
| 10      | Foo    |
```

Here the `Sale No` is added and the query is grouped by all fields that are not being aggregated.

```
 SELECT     [Sale No]
            , Widget
            , COUNT(Widget) As [Total Sold]
 FROM       sometable
 GROUP BY   [Sale No]
            , Widget
```

This would return this table:

```
| Sale No | Widget | Total Sold |
|---------|--------|------------|
| 1       | Bar    | 1          |
| 1       | Foo    | 1          |
| 5       | Bar    | 1          |
| 5       | Foo    | 2          |
| 7       | Bar    | 2          |
| 7       | Foo    | 2          |
| 10      | Foo    | 1          |
```

**Edit:**
Based on the provided table this SQL should give the correct result:

```
SELECT      T1.Department
            , T1.Employee
            , T1.Policy
            , COUNT(T2.Policy)
FROM        sometable T1 INNER JOIN sometable T2 ON T1.Policy = T2.Policy
GROUP BY    T1.Department
            , T1.Employee
            , T1.Policy
```

Resulting table:

```
| Department | Employee | Policy  | Expr1003 |
|------------|----------|---------|----------|
| Accounting | 789      | PlanXYZ | 3        |
| Accounting | 101112   | PLanXYZ | 3        |
| Admin      | 161718   | PLanJKL | 1        |
| Sales      | 123      | PlanABC | 1        |
| Sales      | 456      | PalnABC | 1        |
| Sales      | 131415   | PlanXYZ | 3        |
```

Comment: I don't this is really getting at what I'm trying to do. Here's what I'm looking for. Grab all records from myquery where the status = foo. For each returned record count the number of times this other field occurs in the same table. Essentially this is a two stage operation. It's just for a report, I just need to run in minutes - not hours. I'm hoping there's a way to store that second part in memory so I don't have to keep running Count(*) From table where field = "valuefrompart1"

Comment: Could you add some example data to your question that reflects your actual data.